# How to add image on the top of status bar like this and move it to the progress value in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, progress-bar

[image]Hello community i want to add image on the progress bars progress value , currently i have made the progress bar like this but i am still not figuring out on how to add arrow like in the image on the top of the progress , if the progress is 10 so the arrow should be on the 10 position